# User sign-in process in Django not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm encountering an issue with the user sign-in functionality in my Django application. When attempting to sign in a user, I'm consistently receiving an error message stating "email and/or password is not valid!" instead of successfully logging in the user. I have verified that the email and password inputs are correct. I've also checked my code and ensured that I'm using the authenticate() and login() functions correctly.

here is the code i tried, keep in mind that i am able to regester new users but not able to sign them in:

```
def signup(request):
    # Extract data from form and assign it to variables.
    if request.method =='POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']
        # Check if user exists.
        user_exsit = User.objects.filter(Q(username = username) | Q(email = email)).exists()
        if user_exsit:
            error_message= 'User name or email already exists!'
            return render(request, 'user_auth/signup.html', {'error_message': error_message})
        # Check if the password match. ((JS))
        if password != confirm_password:
            error_message = "Password does not match!"
            return render(request, 'user_auth/signup.html', {'error_message': error_message})
        # Create new user.
        else:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username = username, email = email, password = password)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'user_auth/signin.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'user_auth/signup.html')
    

def signin(request):
    # Extract data from form.
    if request.method=='POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # Create an authenticated user object.
        user = authenticate(request, username= email, password = password)
        # login user if valid and redirect user.
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'user_auth/main.html')
            # If user is not valid.
        else:
            context = 'email and or password is not valid!'
            return render(request, 'user_auth/signin.html', {'context':context})
    return render(request,'user_auth/signin.html')
```

Comment: Have you set up an alternate authenticate method? If so, can you include it?

Comment: it looks like you're using `request.POST['username']` when registering the user, but then you're using `request.POST['email']` when you are trying to log in. So unless the `username` and `email` are identical, this cant work, unless you explicitly set the `email` field as `username`. But there's not enough information to determine this.